# Poor wifi connection causing iPad app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, wifi

I have an app in which there is a routine to sync with our SQL database. I am having some issues with what appears to be poor wifi access.

The routine works like this:

1 - UIButton pressed

2 - Internet connection is checked and if there is connection ....

3 - A new thread is started to display the 'Loading' animated gif

4 - The next page is loaded.

```
if([self connectedToInternet] == YES)
{
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadAnimation) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

ObViewControllerAdminMenu *monitorMenuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webObservations"];
monitorMenuViewController.modalTransitionStyle = IModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:monitorMenuViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then, using the viewDidLoad method in the webObservations page I begin to connect to the SQL database.

My question is what might happen if the internet connection is dropped during the syncing process? It appears to me that the app 'times out' and due to lack of response it shuts itself down.

I think I am right in saying that the iPad does this after 5 seconds of inactivity - is this correct? And if so what are the ways around it?

A snippet of the syncing code is below if that helps:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *strURLClass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://www.website.co.uk/uploads/getiobserveinfo.php?schoolname=",obsSchoolName];
NSArray *observationsArrayClass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURLClass]];
NSEnumerator *enumForObsClass = [observationsArrayClass objectEnumerator];

observationListFromSQL = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

id className, dateOfObs,  teacher, startTime;

while (className = [enumForObsClass nextObject])
{
[observationListFromSQL addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:className, @"obsClassName", nil]];
}
```

From the crash log - note that it runs the routine on launch also

Date/Time:       2013-09-20 11:56:31.731 +0300
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
uk.co.website failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.080 (user 2.080, system 0.000), 5% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.312, 1% CPU

Comment: well, I am not aware of objective-c but it sounds like something exception handling should solve ( at least that its not crashing any more but able to handle it with a "retry" button )

Comment: @Richard Please add the crash logs.

Comment: @Amar I have added a piece of the crash log. I think this suggests a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is:Application Specific Information: uk.co.website failed to launch in time

Please avoid using the sync function to retrieve network resource, initWithContentsOfURL will only return when it download the full url from network.
This method call will block the application to start.

There is async method to download resource such as NSURLConnection or use third party library like AFNetworking

Answer (score 1):

The error code `0x000000008badf00d` means your app is not getting crashed but rather is killed by iOS because your app UI freeze and it took too long to respond. I suspect this line is the culprit,

```
NSArray *observationsArrayClass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURLClass]];
```

This is a synchronous method getting called on the main thread thus causing UI to freeze until watchdog timeout occurs and your app gets killed.

**Solution**

Make asynchronous WS call so that the main thread is not blocked. You can use GCD to achieve this.

```
- (void)doAsyncCall
{
    //you can use any string instead "com.mycompany.myqueue"
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        //Make WS call here.
        //Parse response and create datasource for your UI elements

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Pass the datasource to the UI and update.
        });    
    });
 }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: A very helpful answer - thank you. I will look into this and work out what bits go where and let you know. Thanks for your time.